# curl_setopt(): Filename cannot be empty

Tags: php, selenium, automated-tests, codeception

I try to run test and get this error

```
In Acceptance.php line 97:
```

curl_setopt(): Filename cannot be empty

My Acceptence.php file

```
 $imgPath = codecept_output_dir() .'debug/fail.png';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, [
        'chat_id'   => $chatID,
        'photo'     => new \CURLFile(realpath($imgPath))
    ]);
```

Comment: `realpath` returns false ( which is effectively `empty` ) if the path cannot be found - verify the path (`$imgPath`) is 100% correct. Should there be a slash before `debug` for instance?

Comment: I don't see how this code could have created this error. It's valid to have an empty POST parameter and it's valid to pass an empty value to the CURLFile constructor.

Comment: can you add the code from `acceptance.php` and indicate which is line `97` where this error occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem, the fact was that the function "codecept_output_dir()" was pulling the wrong path and an error occurred because of this. Thank you for your advice-answers)